# Why does VkKeyScanW return -1 for unicode characters?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode, sendinput

I am trying to translates characters to the corresponding virtual-key code using VkKeyScanW function. It works well with the ASCII characters but fails when a unicode character (chinese/russian character) is passed.

```
short vcode = VkKeyScanW(ch); //ch is of wchar_t type;
cout<<"key code:"<<vcode<<endl; //always prints -1 for unicode characters.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way to achieve it? I want to pass the virtual-key code to the SendInput function.

[VkKeyScanW function documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The [`VkKeyScan()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329.aspx) says:

> Translates a character to the corresponding virtual-key code and shift state **for the current keyboard**.
>
> ...
>
> Return value
>
> ...
>
> **If the function finds no key that translates to the passed character code**, both the low-order and high-order bytes contain –1.

So clearly, it is not able to find a matching key code in the current keyboard layout for the Unicode characters you are passing it.

Try using [`LoadKeyboardLayout()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`VkKeyScanEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646332(v=vs.85).aspx) instead, making sure to select a Chinese/Russian keyboard layout.

Also keep in mind that `VkKeyScanW()` and `VkKeyScanExW()` only accept 1 `WCHAR` as input, but languages like Chinese usually require 2 `WCHAR` values working together as a *surrogate pair* to form a Unicode character.  Such characters would not be usable with `VkKeyScan/Ex()`.

That being said, you don't need to translate Unicode characters into virtual key codes in order to use `SendInput()`.  It can accept Unicode characters directly, using its `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag.  In the case of surrogate pairs, you would simply specify two input events, one for each `WCHAR`.